# Power BI Power Query

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have an excel sheet which contains a yearly budget. The sample looks lie this  :

[original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x97E.png)

There is a product name, region,month, week number and the corresponding amount.
How can I approach this issue using Power Bi Query or any other tool to achieve something close to this ([Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8WA5.png))